# how do I use templates stored in a database for smarty?

Tags: php, sql, database, smarty

how can I use the display function or fetch function of smarty on templates I have in a database?

I could get that template using a query, but from there on... i'm stuck.

anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with Smarty, and I do not think Smaty should exists, as PHP is a strong enough templating language (see ZF). BUT, show us the string that is being fetched by the query, give a short example.

Comment: the string is the same as one would find in a .tpl file that smarty uses it's basically just html with {$tag} tags

Answer (score 0):

Google says...

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=37&sid=277600ede9d67d68bb2521722fe8f011

Comment: i'm sorry but this isn't what i'm looking? cant I just edit the fetch function I tried to edit that function but I couldn't find the part where it actually fetches the data from the file any ideas where in smarty's source this is?

Comment: I think if you try to roll your own fetching system you are going to short circuit the transformations and caching that smarty does to templates.